# not receiving any AccessibilityEvent of type TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START

Tags: android, touch, accessibility

I'm trying to create an AccessibilityService that remap touch input, thus I need to intercept touch events.

I've noticed that there are AccessibilityEvent of types [`TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START) and [`TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END) added in API 17 (Android 4.2).

However, when I test my code, targeting API 17, on a Android 4.2 emulator, I cannot receive such events, but all other events like `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` are received properly.

Am I missing something?

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.onthewings.touchservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".TouchService"
            android:label="TouchService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My accessibility_service_config.xml:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackVisual"
    android:notificationTimeout="0"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out, `TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START` and `TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END` will only be received when "touch exploration mode" is turned on (by any service).

Comment: how can i set touch exploration mode on??

Answer (score 2):

Should add

```
android:accessibilityFlags="*|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode" android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
```

in `<accessibility-service>` node:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="50" />
```